# justify-content: space-between not spacing buttons

Tags: css, reactjs

Justify-content: space-between isn't spacing the two buttons. They're side-by-side with no margin. How do I make the buttons space-between?

```js
export const Divbuttons = styled.div`
  display: 'flex';
  flex-direction: 'row';
  justify-content: 'space-between';
  align-items: 'center';
  padding: 0px;
  position: 'absolute';
`;

export const Continue = styled.button`
  line-height: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1.25px;
  padding: 10px 23px;
  box-sizing: 'border-box';
  position: 'static';
`;

export const Cancel = styled.button`
  line-height: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1.25px;
  padding: 10px 23px 10px 23px;
  box-sizing: 'border-box';
  position: 'static';
`;
```

```html
<Divbuttons>
    <Cancel type='button'>Cancel</Cancel>
    <Continue type='button'>Save and continue</Continue>
</Divbuttons>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it looks like you need to remove your quotes. e.g. display: flex; instead of display: 'flex';